# How to RESET Arraylist at the end of the week?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

1. I have an arraylist:

   ```
   ArrayList<String> wholeWeekArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
   ```
2. DatabaseHelper(SQLite) is storing the values into the(above) arrayList:

   ```
   Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
   while (data.moveToNext() ) {
       wholeWeekArrayListString.add(data.getString(1));
       //getString(1) is column values from SQLite
   }
   ```
3. Then I have `SumofWeek` where all the data in `wholeWeekArrayListString` is added together. 
   (I Convert `wholeWeekArrayListString` to double to view it in a TEXTVIEW);
4. I want this `SumOfWeek` to reset to Zero at the end of the week but the data inside the SQLite must keep adding(for `SumOfMonth` view).

   So by Sunday the data may be `$50.00` (for Example) and Starting on int Monday. the data must reset to `0.0` and sum all the way up until Sunday.
   This must happen weekly.

How would u do this? I have tried assining days of weeks.

```
Monday =1;
Tuesday = 2;
Wednesday =3;
// ...
```

and iterate through the whole week but Im not able to get(i), which is the data of each single day of the week and then reset it on which is

```
int Sunday =7;
```

I have the total amount but dont know what method to use to reset the data at the end of the week?

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the DB calls, you´ll have to store the timestamp of the latest reset (resetTimestamp in the example below). If the current time is in a different week, the code will trigger a reset of sumofWeek. After that, it´s your normal sumofWeek logic.

Thread safety: to be added depending on the application specifics.

```
    private ArrayList<Long> sumofWeek = new ArrayList<>(); 
    private Long resetTimestamp;

    public void populateWeek() {
        if(resetTimestamp == null || isDifferentWeek(resetTimestamp)) {
            sumofWeek = new ArrayList<Long>();
            for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
                sumofWeek.add(0l);
            }
            System.out.println(sumofWeek);
            resetTimestamp = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        // populate sumofWeek here
    }

    private boolean isDifferentWeek(long resetTimestamp) {
        Calendar cl1 = new GregorianCalendar();
        cl1.setTimeInMillis(java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis());

        Calendar cl2 = new GregorianCalendar();
        cl2.setTimeInMillis(resetTimestamp);

        return cl1.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) != cl2.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR); 
    }
```